# how to have checkbox on right of label

Tags: html, css, reactjs, layout

I am trying to write a react js app, and I cannot figure out how to have my checkbox appear to the right of the label rather than below it. I tried inline block, block, but they are still only appearing below the labels and I cannot figure it out.

Adding Inline block to a div class for the labels made the labels appear next to one another, but the checkbox still appears below them.

Flexbox, inline, and float also did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex position.
You can add the property `order` to reverse your children elements.

```css
label {
  order: 1;
}

input {
  order: 2
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class='content'>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" />
  <label for="checkbox1">My checkbox is  on the right</label>
</div>
```

Comment: this still is not working

Comment: I updated the answer with another solution for you.